# Integrate Private Alexa Skill in my own app

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex, alexa-voice-service

I have been searching everywhere to find a right answer but couldn't find it. I have an Private Alexa Skill. What I want to do is to implement the Alexa Voice Service in an mobile App to access that Skill. So in that app, i click a button and say:

"Alexa, start MyPrivatSkill" --> and it starts my private skill and i have access to that skills functionality. I know I probably have to use Alexa for Business for that. But otherwise, is it possible to achieve that?

Or is that something that is better realized with Amazon Lex? Because my Skill is mostly simple Question->Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa for business is one way to go. But it comes with a cost as well (Each shared device costs $7 per month, and each enrolled user costs $3 per month). Also, Alexa for Business is available in the US East (N. Virginia) region only. You can try Amazon Lex but there is catch of language being US-en only (As of now), plus it also has a cost. you can process up to 10,000 text requests and 5,000 speech requests per month for free for the first year. After that, You are charged based on the number of text or voice requests processed by your bot, at $0.004 per voice request, and $.00075 per text request.

You have decide which way to go, based on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Alexa private skills only work on registered echo devices, or like you said the [business account](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-for-business/create-and-publish-private-skills.html#step-6-distribute-a-private-skill) so the best way to use your skill is to provide an API gateway function mapped to a lambda endpoint which just uses your skill's logic and returns a json object of the text needed.